Get PythonTkinter width of string in pixels using given font
Given a string such as "this is a string" or "THIS IS A STRING" and knowing the font family and size, how can the pixel width be calculated?
This is required to align columns for an eyesome GUI.

There is a method measure() of Font object to give the width in pixels of a string:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
font = Font(family='Arial', size=20)

for s in ('this is a string', 'THIS IS A STRING'):
    w = font.measure(s)
    print(f'Width of "{s}" is {w} pixels')

Output:
Width of "this is a string" is 169 pixels
Width of "THIS IS A STRING" is 231 pixels

Document on measure().
